docusign having expired_client_token
I'm working with docusign and i tried to generate a token with 01 Authorize Code Grant Access Token API: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token .
I followed the documentation https://developers.docusign.com/tools/postman/ i generated the code and encodedKeys but i'm getting this error:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "expired_client_token"
}

What i'm missing?

The authorisation code you generated has expired - they are only valid for 2 minutes and are one time use after being generated. You should regenerate it and try again.
